# Were the English behind the creation of Belgium?

Tags: france, united-kingdom, belgium

The other day I read an article in a printed newspaper which explained that the British had a tradition of trying to break any continental power (links to recent news is not a coincidence).

Among the examples provided, the author argued that (paraphrasing... and translating)

> Belgium was created by the British to prevent France having access to the harbours in Northern Europe, and in particular Antwerp (Anvers).

Now, it was my understanding that Begium resulted from the (*de facto* at the end of the 16th Century and *de jure* at the end of the 80 years wars in the mid-17th Century) separation of the Netherlands from the Spanish Low-Lands.

At that time the English had other things to do (like preparing a civil war), and France looked less like a menace than the Spanish (even if they were on a descending slope).

I know that towards the end of the 17th Century, Louis XIV's France fought regular wars in the region, in particular against the Netherlands, and that the two of them played some kind of "funny" games with post-Civil war England.

Later, Belgium was included in the French Empire from 1793 to 1815.

So I don't know to which time does the author refer to, but **is there any documentation that indicates a strong support of England to the creation of Belgium to spite the French?**

---

I am aware of the question

[What led to the creation of Belgium?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-led-to-the-creation-of-belgium)

But, if this explains the different steps of the creation of Belgium, nothing is provided regarding the specifics of my question, namely the possible implication of Great Britain and the economic influence of France.

Comment: it regard the british policy was the to oppose any one power dominating europe, and major power controlling the ports of the low countries.

Comment: Any claim that X was caused by Y in international relations is an oversimplification that obscures truth.  The statement that "Belgium was created by the British.... " implies a degree of agency to the British government that is not supported by facts.  Correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace While true, it does not exclude it neither. So this is really my question, isn't it? Do we have any proof that it was more than correlation?

Comment: Possibly whoever made that claim had in mind the family connection between Leopold I of Belgium and Queen Victoria. Anyhow, this seems to be a mostly harmless conspiracy theory.

Comment: The most likely reference is the outcome of the 1830 revolution (that ended with Belgium becoming independent from the Netherlands) and the UK granting the independence of the newly formed kingdom.

Comment: Perhaps one should say that English policy favored the creation of Belgium at the time, and that there were *enough* supporters of Belgian statehood to make it happen. It will be hard to tell whose support "tipped the scales" to "cause" the event.

Comment: "Modern Belgium" was a creation of King Leopold II and New York City. Neither Britain nor France nor Germany took seriously the Nation's efforts to create a vast Colonial Empire for itself....something it did in fact do. Certain British subjects had a critical role in this but certainly not Great Britain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a conspiracy theory

Comment: @TomAu not at all. My question specifically asks about the involvement of GB and repercussion on France during the creation of Belgium. None of those are mentioned in any of the answer of that other question.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens is it? Do you have any reference to that? Or you just decided that it is based on...? I'd be perfectly happy with an answer that says: "No there are no documents about it". Maybe with a bit more flesh...

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin: At SE, "duplicate" means that the answers are duplicate, not the questions. So if the answers to the other question don't mention the English, the answer to your question is "no" by process of elimination.

Comment: @TomAu I know, this is why I mentioned "None of those are mentioned in any of the answer of that other question". If someone was asking how Syria's event started... it won't probably be mentioned that the USA as well as others countries have been providing weapons to some rebel group. That's called context. The context of that other question is different that this one. So leave it open, but neither me, nor anyone who would wonder about that will get the answer.

Answer (score 7):

In 1830 the Netherlands was a minor power, not a great power.  The Netherlands had been a rival of England in the mid 17th century but in the early 19th century it was no rival of the United Kingdom.  England, Great Britain, and the UK did not like major powers controlling the nearest  ports in what is now Belgium.

The 19th century Netherlands was no great power so England had no motive to break it up.  When Belgium did revolt The leaders of the UK thought that was good for the UK because the power controlling the ports would now be even more minor.  However, it would turn out to be bad for the UK if a major power like France managed to annex Belgium.

So the diplomatic interest of the UK was to do what it could through diplomacy to back the independence of Belgium and to oppose French moves to annex any part of Belgium.

So the UK did not conceive or give birth to Belgium but their statesmen were probably quite willing to be godparents and sponsors at the baptism.

Comment: In addition it can be said that when the Netherlands army defeated the Belgians in 1830 a new war loomed between the Netherlands and France. Britain and Prussia actively intervened to prevent such a war, that would inevitably become a new European war. The compromise that was acceptable to everyone except the Dutch king William, was the new kingdom of Belgium.